# Worksheet_change Event not triggered when vba macro used

Tags: excel, events, triggers, vba

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim C As Range, A As Range, D As Range

    Set C = Range("F121:F218")
    Set A = Range("AB121")
    Set D = Range("G236:G261")

    If Not Application.Intersect(C, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then Call Macro1 

    If Not Application.Intersect(A, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then Call Macro2 

    If Not Application.Intersect(D, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then Call Macro3

End Sub
```

The code works when I change the target cells by myself in excel, but when I use a macro to change them, event trigger doesn't work.

What is the reason for this?

I believe that it is because my target cells is having a formula and even though the value is changing the formula in the cells is not and that is why the trigger is not fired. But then the question is how do I make it trigger by both a value change and calculation?

Comment: Could you explain what this macro is _doing_?  You want a macro to change a cell to trigger an event to run a different macro?

Comment: Or you're want the _OnChange_ event to change a cell and trigger an _OnChange_ event?

Comment: This macro is supposed trigger other macros when the cell values changes, these other macros is changing the color of the cells in the target area.

Comment: @Deldar22 What is value of `Application.EnableEvents` when you use a macro? If you set it to `False` at the start of the macro or right before changing cells, it will not trigger `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. It is an old code. I think it can be remove without impacting the code

Comment: @Deldar22 Are `Macro1`,`Macro2`,`Macro3` are similiar to each other? Can you post one for example? There might be something that stops macro from triggering.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: The event is not triggered because none of your `If`s is `True`?

Comment: No, the cells are having a value. the cells contains is a formula that calculate a value based on cells in other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forcibly call of your event-handler from another macros by:

```
Application.Run ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name_of_your_sheet").CodeName & ". Worksheet_Change"
```